# Internet after task wakeup

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I have created a task to wake up the laptop from hib each 2 hours and run a .bat file.
Inside that .bat file I run a python script.
Inside that python script I have something like this:

```
temp_timeout = 3
while temp_timeout:
    try:
        response = urlopen('http://google.com', timeout=1)
        return
    except URLError:
        print("No internet")
        os.system("netsh wlan disconnect interface=NAME")
        time.sleep(10)
        os.system("netsh wlan connect name=NAME ssid=SSID")
        time.sleep(10)
        temp_timeout = temp_timeout - 1
        pass
    quit()

#do some stuff and go to hibernation
```

The problem is that from 10 wakeups I get "No internet"(x3) 2-3 times and the rest of 8-7 it's working properly. What could be the problem, why it is not working every time?

Comment: In some cases in windows the internet isn't connected so fast after wakeup, maybe it took some time and thus `No internet`.

Comment: Do you understand what the code you posted does?

Comment: @faruk13 more that 20 sec * 3? I'm sure it's not the case.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, what is the problem?

Comment: You seem to want to have an internet connection established. It's not clear why you believe that disconnecting a network adapter were part of the solution.

Comment: @IInspectable I am checking if there is internet, if not then disconnect and connect again, so I'm not only disconnecting.

Comment: You aren't checking, whether you have internet connection. You are checking, whether you can access a particular network resource. Now even if your conclusion that if you cannot access the resource would indeed mean, that you did not have internet connection, what's the rationale behind disconnecting? You assume to be disconnected already, so why do it? Just in case? For good measure? Since none of that makes any sense to me I specifically asked, whether you understood the code you posted.

Comment: @IInspectable Since 7 out of 10 times it is working (there is a connection to the network resource) I assume that on those 3 times that is not working there must be some init problem, that's why I disconnect and reconnect, maybe it will do the init properly this time. Do you have a better idea to check where the problem is, why some random times I can not access that particular network resource?

Comment: I don't know, what the issue is. But this is a quote from Einstein: [Insanity Is Doing the Same Thing Over and Over Again and Expecting Different Results](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/03/23/same/). That should be a guiding principle in any engineering endeavour. I'd probably just wait for internet connectivity becoming available, in parallel to a failure timeout.